# Calling data from a div to share on social media using cordova social sharing plugin

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've got the cordova social sharing plugin which allows me to share info on social media to my friends. But what i've noticed is the info shared cannot be dynamic and it always have to be static.
What i want to achieve its there's an info i load in a div called `"data"` with ajax and i want that information loaded in the div `data` to be the one shared on the social media

```
<button class="invite" data-role="none" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Static info')">Share Message with a Friend</button>
```

I'm using this plugin for the social sharing

```
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a small function, which simply retrieves the data and passes it to the plugin.

You could retrieve the data with jQuery, but you could also hold a reference to the data retrieved by ajax and pass that to the function.

Finally attach the function to the button click. The example below fetches the data from a div with id data:

```js
function shareMessage() {
  var message = $("#data").html();
  alert(message); //for demo purpose only
  //window.plugins.socialsharing.share(message); //uncomment this line to use the plugin
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data">Some custom message loaded with ajax</div>

<button class="invite" data-role="none" onclick="shareMessage()">Share Message with a Friend</button>
```

Comment: it didn't work it only pops up a alert in the app but fails to initailize the sharing plugin

Comment: Look at the comments in the function. Remove the alert line and uncomment the call to the plugin

Comment: it worked but it ignore all the paragraphs in the text making it clumpsy. is there a way to format the text while removing all html attributes but maintaing the formatting?